# override ajax beforeSend globally

Tags: javascript, jquery

so we have this ajax option beforeSend

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     // to do
   }
 });
```

is there a way to override this globally?

for example, i want to insert a function on all ajax and I want to do this by creating a single function rather than going all $.ajax calls one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the **.ajaxStart()** - it's global for all AJAX calls.

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether
>   there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in
>   progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers
>   that have been registered with the .ajaxStart() method are executed at
>   this time.

More info @ https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/